# Linear second order differential equation with non-constant parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this second order linear differential equation that has non-constant parameter $x$ next to $y$:

$(x^2+1)y''-2xy'+2y=6(x^2+1)$

Using methods I was taught that you can either use $x=e^t$ or $x^\lambda = y$, I tried using $x=e^t$ where $y'=y'_t e^{-t}$ and $y''=e^{-2t}(y''_t-y'_t)$. This is what I get:

$(1+e^{-2t})y''_t-(1+e^{2t})y'_t-3y'_t+2y=6e^{2t}+6$

I am trying to get rid of $e^{something}$ parts so I get homogenous differential equation. Is there something I could do now to make it like I want or my method is completely wrong?

Comment: This looks like a classic Method Frobenius, power series type question, I'm not sure why that particular transformation should work here.

Comment: I am quite limited with tools I can use while solving these equations so I am trying every method I was taught to solve it.  The only method we were taught is this or if you were given a one particular integral to find the other one and then combine two particular integrals in one solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inspection, $y=x$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation, so you could try **reduction of order** to find the general solution to the homogeneous equation, and then **variation of constants** to find a particular solution matching the right-hand side.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I am trying to write it down and will respond back if that's not problem.